# Pick a random item in specific list range python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x

```
Pool_of_games = [[[0,2,3,1,3,2,0,1],"PdPd","PrisonerDilemma"],
[[0,3,2,1,2,3,0,1],"ShSh","StagHunt"],
[[1,2,3,0,3,2,1,0],"ChCh","Chicken"],
[[2,1,3,0,3,1,2,0],"BaBa","Battle"]]

#%%
# Random Strategy Selection: ramdomly choose a strategy within each player's strategy profile for each game in the input list

def RandomStrategySelection():
```

Hello, I have the following input, I am trying to pick and store in a variable two random items (numbers) inside the first brackets in the list, However I need to define a range where each variable is supposed to choose, one of them needs to select an item among the four first values and the second variable then will choose one of the remaining items, I need to do this for all items. Ive been trying a couple of stuff but I couldnt get it working, any Ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: something like `[random.choice(i[0]) for i in Pool_of_games]` will choose a random value from each of the list of integers in `Pool_of_games`, but not sure how you want to "define a range where each variable is supposed to choose"

Comment: Hi @downshift, thank you very much for your hint, I have figured it out :)